# What is the reason for an error within Dash elements properties?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I have been working with Dash and Plotly for Python for quite a while now. Everything was working (in fact, it still does). The problem is I opened VS Code this morning and I have a bunch of highlighted errors on all my .py files. They all show an error like this:

Argument of type "list[dict[str, Any]]" cannot be assigned to parameter "options" of type "_UNDEFINED" in function "**init**"
"list[dict[str, Any]]" is incompatible with "_UNDEFINED"

This was not here when I last worked on this project (about two days ago). I can still run the web app and it works as expected, but it is really hard to keep working when I have all this highlighted text for apparently no reason.

[Screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llUb5.png)

Does anyone know why this could have happened overnight, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have inadvertently switched type checking on.
In VSC, hover over the curly braces next to 'Python' that appears in the footer at the bottom of the application window to toggle it on and off.

[image: VSC footer]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that you haven't choosen the Python interpreter in your IDE. Select it from the setting of your IDE.